# MPC arithmetic circuit file and benchmark

Tags: multiparty-computation, arithmetic, circuit

For doing MPC over Boolean circuits (typically XOR, AND, INV gates over field of size 2), Boolean circuit files can be found online for a range of interesting functions (e.g. AES, SHA-256). These circuit files can then be used in different implementations in order to compare performance.

For arithmetic circuits (ADD, MUL gates over larger rings), is there such a thing as an arithmetic circuit file? Are there by now accepted functions/circuits which one can use as a benchmark to compare different MPC protocol implementations over arithmetic circuits?